# Django Tutorial 3 - URL producing 404 error

Tags: python, django

I am following the Django 1.6 tutorial 3 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) and I have become stuck towards the beginning - "Writing your first view".

The Django tutorial first says to edit the **views.py**, which I have done as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

Then it says to create a **urls.py** in the same directory, which I have done. My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The next instruction is to now check the URL `http://localhost:8000/polls/` for the message 'Hello, world. You're at the poll index.' but my browser simply produces the Django 404 error - Page not found.

I'm sure I'm doing something pretty stupid but I can't what is wrong, I've tried restarting the python webserver. I've followed the previous 2 tutorials with success, can anybody help me out?

If it makes a difference, I'm using Windows7, Python 3.4.1 and Django 1.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `view.py` for `polls` must be in `projectname/polls/` directory when first `urls.py` will be in `projectname/projectname/`.

Then, if you decide to configure and add more polls app specific urls, you can create `urls.py` in `projectname/polls/`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't quite understand there was a root urls.py aswell!